# secure Websocket not working using AWS ELB + Cloudflare SSL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, websocket, cloudflare, amazon-elb

I'm building a chat using websocket in php.

Everything work's fine using ws but i receive an error 504 bad gateway when i try to use wss (secure).

SSL in use is the default one on cloudflare (full, always use https) and all traffic without www are redirected to www

My websocket use port 8443 that work on cloudflare

On AWS i use a application load balancer containing only 1 instance and security group allow port 8443 as it work without the secure Websocket.

Any idea where my problem could be ?

Comment: can you please post the code that you are using?

Comment: Why are you not using the standard port, 443?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot "wss" on port 8443 or 443 both return error 504 Gateway Time-out while working using "ws"

Comment: @SuitBoyApps   

JS:
var wsUri = "wss://www.domain.com:8443/chatServer.php";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
  
websocket.onopen = function(data) {alert('good');}

PHP:
$host = 'www.domain';
$port = '8443';

$null = NULL;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
socket_listen($socket);
$clients = array($socket);